# Difference between custom numeric formatters with group formatters?

Tags: .net, string, number-formatting

The MSDN documentation is not very clear on this, unfortunately. I'm wondering what the difference is between the following numeric formatters.

1. `#,#`
2. `#,0`
3. `#,#0`
4. `#,##0`
5. `#,###0` (not sure this is even valid as I'm not currently able to test)

As far as I can tell, they would all format numbers such as `12345` as `12,345`. Surely there is some subtle difference though in certain cases?

Finally, are there any valid format strings with specifiers to the left of `#,#` or `#,0`? If so, what do they do?

Comment: Any more info please...?

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a difference with (3).

Here's the code I knocked up:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] arrFormat = new string[] { "{0:#,0}", "{0:#,#0}", "{0:#,##}", "{0:#,###0}" };
    int[] ints = new int[] {0, 1, 10, 19, 100, 123, 1234, 12345};
    double[] doubles = new double[]{ 0, 0.1, 1.1, 10.12, 100.1, 123.45, 
                                     12334.4567, 1234.56, 12345.6};

    foreach (string specifier in arrFormat)
    {
        Console.Write(specifier + ":\t\t" );

        foreach (int i in ints)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format(specifier, i) + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");

    foreach (string specifier in arrFormat)
    {
        Console.Write(specifier + ":\t\t");

        foreach (double d in doubles)
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format(specifier, d) + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
{0:#,0}:                0, 1, 10, 19, 100, 123, 1,234, 12,345,
{0:#,#0}:               0, 1, 10, 19, 100, 123, 1,234, 12,345,
{0:#,##}:               , 1, 10, 19, 100, 123, 1,234, 12,345,
{0:#,###0}:             0, 1, 10, 19, 100, 123, 1,234, 12,345,
-------------------------------------------
{0:#,0}:                0, 0, 1, 10, 100, 123, 12,334, 1,235, 12,346,
{0:#,#0}:               0, 0, 1, 10, 100, 123, 12,334, 1,235, 12,346,
{0:#,##}:               , , 1, 10, 100, 123, 12,334, 1,235, 12,346,
{0:#,###0}:             0, 0, 1, 10, 100, 123, 12,334, 1,235, 12,346,
```

[If someone wants to improve the test cases, feel free.]

SteveX's article is a very good reference for format strings: [String Formatting in C#](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Comment: Apologies; I wrote this post rather late and 3. was actually a typo. I fixed that case and added an extra one. Feel free to test again; or since you've posted the code, I can try myself when I get some time. Thanks for the resource too.